# Why is this UPDATE query not using an index?

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

I have a query:

```
 EXPLAIN UPDATE myTable SET col2 = 'foo' WHERE col1 = 'bar';
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | myTable     | NULL       | index | myTable_ind_indx1     | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 890860 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Which uses the `PRIMARY` key instead of using the correct index `myTable_ind_indx1`. Here's the relevant part of the table creation statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  ...
  `col1` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `myTable_ind_indx1` (`col1`,`col3`),
  ...
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

So it's doing a full table scan instead of using the correct index. At first I thought this is because the query planner estimates the number of rows as ~900k and the total is ~1M, but if I count the number of rows matching the WHERE clause it's actually ~250k and besides even adding a `USE INDEX` results in the exact same plan. Changing the query to a `SELECT` results in the correct index being used. This is on MySQL 8.0.19. Any ideas on what I can do to improve things?

Comment: Tried that. Same plan.

Comment: Well, if the condition "col1 = 'bar'" matches 250k rows from 1M, that's 25% of your table, that means the update will modify almost all pages of the table, because almost every page will contain at least one row matching the condition (unless there is some direct connection between id and col1 but the optimizer would not know anyway).  And if it has to rewrite almost the entire table there is no way skipping randomly using the index would be better than just doing full table scan.

Comment: Why is there a difference between `SELECT` and `UPDATE` then? I'd expect the same logic to have the `SELECT` query not use the index either, but that's not the case.

Comment: what is the SELECT version you use? it might lead to index-only query.

Comment: @jkavalik `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 = 'bar'`.

Comment: @Johnny ok, that I would expect to behave the same generally, unless the optimizer gives significantly different estimates. But there might be a difference in the threshold for reading and writing (don't know if there is in v8).

Comment: @jkavalik - It's an `UPDATE`, so it can't be "index-only".  Meanwhile, your first Comment should be presented as an Answer.

Comment: @RickJames the select “test” version could be index-only :)

Comment: @RickJames so is there no way to make this run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition `col1 = 'bar'` matches 250k rows from 1M, that's *25%* of your table, that means the update will modify almost *all pages* of the table, because almost *every page* will contain at least one row matching the condition (unless there is some direct connection between `id` and `col1` but the optimizer would not know anyway).

And when it has to rewrite almost the entire table there is no way skipping randomly using the index would be better than just doing full table scan. The optimizer is choosing the right plan.

If the rows were actually clustered in one part of the table (there were some correlation between `id` and `col1`) then you could tell that to the optimizer by adding the `id` range to the `WHERE` clause. But without that a full table scan is just the fastest way to do it.

For the select it may be different, because it does not have to write things to the disk, it may work with different seq/rand access *"prices"* and utilize caches more. So not having similar plan for `SELECT` and `UPDATE` is maybe unexpected but valid.

Comment: @johnny - Did this speed up the Update?

Answer (score 1):

**Plan A - Chunking**

`UPDATEing` 250K rows takes a long time, *regardless* of indexing, etc.  This is because the Engine hands on to the old values of each of the 250K rows in case you do `ROLLBACK` or the server crashes.  This allows the `UPDATE` to be atomic.

You want it "faster"?  Why?  Is it because you want it to finish sooner; if so, why?  Or, more likely, the `UPDATE` is interfering with other stuff.

In this latter case, you can avoid most of the interference by doing the Update in chunks.  Walk through the `PRIMARY KEY` 1K rows at a time, performing an autocommit'd.  Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

**Plan B -- avoid Update**

```
CREATE TABLE newt LIKE mytable;
INSERT INTO newt
    SELECT ...   -- using either data from mytable or other data
        FROM mytable;
RENAME TABLE mytable TO oldt,
             newt TO mytable;
DROP TABLE oldt;
```

That will have virtually zero impact on other threads *reading* `mytable`.  And it will probably be faster than the Update.